# How do I run a sub() function on a list returned by a findall() function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace text in a string. First I have to use findall() to collect several different occurrences, and then I have to replace them all with one specific string.

Here is the problem:

1. Write a regular expression that will find all occurrances of:
   a.  regular expression
   b.  regular-expression
   c.  regular:expression
   d.  regular&expression
   in search_string
2. Assign the regular expression to a variable named pattern
3. Using the sub() method from the re package substitute all occurrences of the 'pattern' with 'substitution'
4. Assign the outcome of the sub() method to a variable called replace_result
5. Output to the console replace_results

Here is my code:

```
import re
search_string = '''This is a string to search for a regular expression 
like regular expression or regular-expression or regular:expression or 
regular&expression'''
pattern = re.findall('regular.expression', search_string)
substitution = 'regular expression'
replace_results = re.sub('regular.expression', 'regular expression', 
search_string)
print(replace_results)
```

So I know find all returns a list as a result, which causes TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. I can use sub with 'regular.expression' instead, but that doesn't really solve the problem as intended. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: A loop over all the matches from `findall`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but note that the replacement parameter to `re.sub` can be a callable - see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not ask you to use `re.findall` at all. You should search for the pattern with `re.sub` instead and replace the matches with `substitution`:

```
import re
search_string = 'This is a string to search for a regular expression like regular expression or regular-expression or regular:expression or regular&expression'
pattern = 'regular[ -:^]expression'
substitution = 'substitution'
replace_result = re.sub(pattern, substitution, search_string)
print(replace_result)
```

This outputs:

```
This is a string to search for a substitution like substitution or substitution or substitution or substitution
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import re

#The string to search for the regular expression occurrence (This is provided to the student)
search_string='''This is a string to search for a regular expression like regular expression or 
regular-expression or regular:expression or regular&expression'''

#1.  Write a regular expression that will find all occurrances of:
#    a.  regular expression
#    b.  regular-expression
#    c.  regular:expression
#    d.  regular&expression
#    in search_string
text=re.compile(r'regular.\w+')
##2.  Assign the regular expression to a variable named pattern
pattern=text
#The string to use for substitution (This is provided to the student)

substitution="regular expression"

#3.  Using the sub() method from the re package substitute all occurrences of the 'pattern' with 'substitution'
result = re.sub(pattern, substitution, search_string)
#4.   Assign the outcome of the sub() method to a variable called replace_result
replace_result=result
#5.  Output to the console replace_results
print(replace_result)
```

```css
import re

#The string to search for the regular expression occurrence (This is provided to the student)
search_string='''This is a string to search for a regular expression like regular expression or 
regular-expression or regular:expression or regular&expression'''

#1.  Write a regular expression that will find all occurrances of:
#    a.  regular expression
#    b.  regular-expression
#    c.  regular:expression
#    d.  regular&expression
#    in search_string
text=re.compile(r'regular.\w+')
##2.  Assign the regular expression to a variable named pattern
pattern=text
#The string to use for substitution (This is provided to the student)

substitution="regular expression"

#3.  Using the sub() method from the re package substitute all occurrences of the 'pattern' with 'substitution'
result = re.sub(pattern, substitution, search_string)
#4.   Assign the outcome of the sub() method to a variable called replace_result
replace_result=result
#5.  Output to the console replace_results
print(replace_result)
```